# Minecraft Command working in text chat but not in command block 1.14+

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command in a command block that doesn't work. However, it works fine when I put it into text chat.

Here is the command:

```
playsound minecraft:ambient.cave block @a[x=-190,y=78,z=196,distance=..100]
```

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you're not just walking out of range to activate the command block? :D

Comment: Yeah, even if the player was 100 blocks away, the sound would play, but it would play at the command block, which means the player would be out of hearing range

Comment: What happens when you use this command in a command block: `execute as @a[x=-190,y=78,z=196,distance=..100] at @s run playsound minecraft:ambient.cave block @s`?